# writing a filename after each processed line

Tags: bash, for-loop, filenames

I wrote following codes to process each line from multiple files and add filename at the end of the line:

```
for i in $(cat all_output_file.txt);do cat $i|sed 's/:/ /g'|sed 's/-/ /g'| sed 's/,cn=/ /g'| awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print $1,$2,$3,$6,FILENAME}'>>input_file.txt;done
```

however, above code printed "-" at the end of every line instead of filename, how can I print filename at the end of each processed line?

Comment: It is because `awk` is reading from `stdin`

Comment: yes, I figured it out, later on, I stored the processed line in a variable and tried printing filename using "echo" but it is also not working out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because awk is reading from `stdin` not from a file.

Having said that you can do all this in `awk` itself:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{gsub(/[:-]|,cn/, " "); print $1,$2,$3,$6, FILENAME}' "$line" 
done < all_output_file.txt >>input_file.txt
```

`gsub` is equivalent of 3 `sed` commands.

[Also check this BASH FAQ on reading a file line by line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

As [@123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123) commented below, you can even avoid the `for` loop and use:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{gsub(/[:-]|,cn/, " ");
    print $1,$2,$3,$6, FILENAME}' $(<all_output_file.txt) >>input_file.txt
```

In BASH `$(<all_output_file.txt)` reads the content of input file.

Comment: Skip the loop and multiple awk forks and just use `awk 'stuff' $(<file)`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Now I have to understand how it worked. Thanks again!